# django data between tests

Tags: python, django, testing

Is it normal for data be deleted after a test success in django? I'm not talking about for each test run, let me do a example:

```
class MyFooTest(TestCase):
    def test_foo1(self):
        # Some foo test code here

    def test_foo2(self):
        # Some foo test code here
```

The data made during test `test_foo1` do not existing when test `test_foo2` is made, is it normal to happens?

Comment: How are you creating data in `test_foo1`?

Comment: Hi, I'm testing `django-rest-framework` endpoints, in `test_foo1` I create an instance of a model in my project. In `test_foo2` I test if the object is correctly taken from the endpoint.

Comment: How are you creating it? Are you just instantiating a new object/model? Or are you using either `create` or `save`?

Comment: I'm using the `create` method, I post the data to my endpoint.

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase), the bottom part explaining the difference between `TransactionTestCase` and `TestCase`:

> A TestCase, on the other hand, does not truncate tables after a test. Instead, it encloses the test code in a database transaction that is rolled back at the end of the test. This guarantees that the rollback at the end of the test restores the database to its initial state.

Since each individual test method is wrapped in an `atomic` block, and each atomic block is rolled back at the end of the test method, this is expected behaviour. Django does this to ensure that tests are isolated, making it easier to find any problems when they occur.

If you need data to persists in multiple test methods, you can create them in [`setUpTestData()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData). Just make sure not to change the in-memory objects created by `setUpTestData()`. The in-memory changes will persists, but the database changes will be rolled back.

Comment: What if we want to post from a test and access it using a get in the following test case? With the rollback happening, this won't be possible.