# testing Profile creation after user registration with uninttest

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

i use signals for create profile after user register, Manually the test and def test__create_profile is correct, but def test_profile_created_automate is false.

this is my test:

```
class Testprofile(APITestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.client = APIClient()
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(email='hosein@gmail.com', username='hosein', password='admin')

def test__create_profile(self):
    response = self.client.post(reverse('users-front:create_profile'), data={
        "user": 1,
        'age': 10,
        "first_name": "string",
        "last_name": "string",
        "phon_number": "9182133038",
        "birthday": "2023-11-21",
        "bio": "string",
        "address": "string",
        "gender": "M"
    })
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 201)

def test_profile_created_automate(self):
    user = User.objects.get(username='hosein')
    self.assertTrue(Profile.objects.filter(user=user).exists())
```

Answer (score 0):

Tests by design do not "keep" the data between them. That is, after `test__create_profile` is done your database is rolled back to the state it was in before the test. The profile you created in `test__create_profile` does not exist any more when you run `test_profile_created_automate`, that's why it fails.

This answer could be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36073951/13204032